# RadComboBox how to change the look of the Selected Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, telerik

I have to provide sorting (ascending, descending, none) for the selected items in the RadComboBox.

I was thinking to make the selected items look as following: on the left side of the item is the text and on the right is a icon which (arrow) shows the sorting direction. Text and Icon are separated by a vertical line. Clicking on the item changes the sorting direction (none → ascending → descending → none).

What I currently have looks like this: 
[image]

And this is what I would like the selected items to look like (Field would be for example LanguageName):
[image]

My question would be how can I define the selected item of the RadComboBox ? Which template do I have to change and how ?

Here is my Source Code:

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customization.Columns}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                                      AllowMultipleSelection="True"
                                      CanAutocompleteSelectItems="True"
                                      CanKeyboardNavigationSelectItems="True"
                                      SelectionChanged="GroupingRadComboBox_OnSelectionChanged"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding GroupByColumn, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <telerik:RadComboBox.IsEnabled>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanAndConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="Customization.Wpf.LoadInMemory"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Customization.Columns.Count" Converter="{StaticResource IsCollectionEmptyToBoolConverter}" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                              </telerik:RadComboBox.IsEnabled
 </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with telerik but probably like the default ComboBox you can set the datatemplate using SelectionBoxItemTemplate property.

Comment: Yes, I tried the SelectionBoxItemTemplate property, I defined a Template but when I try to give something like this: `SelectionBoxItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}"` I get the error that `The Property SelectionBoxItemTemplate does not have an accessible setter`

Could you please make a example ?

Comment: Yes actually it is SelectionBoxTemplate: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/features/populating-with-data-selectionbox

Comment: I see that it is `MultipleSelectionBoxTemplate` but still cant menage to get the wanted result.